# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, beancreationexception

I'm having the following error:

```
11/Ago/2011 14:04:48 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Sun\SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse;
11/Ago/2011 14:04:48 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
11/Ago/2011 14:04:48 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 625 ms
11/Ago/2011 14:04:48 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
11/Ago/2011 14:04:48 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
11/Ago/2011 14:04:48 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ServerTest.xml
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@6293df2c: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Aug 11 14:04:49 BST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@6293df2c]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7df1bd98
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7df1bd98: defining beans [productManager,productDao,dataSource,propertyConfigurer,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0,txAdvice]; root of factory hierarchy
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7df1bd98: defining beans [productManager,productDao,dataSource,propertyConfigurer,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0,txAdvice]; root of factory hierarchy
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productDao' while setting bean property 'productDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:268)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:462)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:268)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
    ... 62 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:206)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:828)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:799)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
    ... 46 more

(etc...)

11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/ServerTest] startup failed due to previous errors
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/ServerTest] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
11/Ago/2011 14:04:49 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1592 ms
```

---

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="productManager" class="ServerTest.service.SimpleProductManager">
        <property name="productDao" ref="productDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="productDao" class="ServerTest.repository.JdbcProductDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* *..ProductManager.*(..))"
            advice-ref="txAdvice" />
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="save*" />
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
</beans>
```

---

My SimpleProductManager.java

```
package ServerTest.service;

import java.util.List;

import ServerTest.domain.Product;
import ServerTest.repository.ProductDao;
import ServerTest.service.ProductManager;

public class SimpleProductManager implements ProductManager {
    // private List<Product> products;
    private ProductDao productDao;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        // return products;
        return productDao.getProductList();
    }

    public void increasePrice(int percentage) {
         List<Product> products = productDao.getProductList();
        if (products != null) {
            for (Product product : products) {
                double newPrice = product.getPrice().doubleValue() * 
                                    (100 + percentage)/100;
                product.setPrice(newPrice);
                productDao.saveProduct(product);
            }
        }             
    }

    public void setProductDao(ProductDao productDao) {
        this.productDao = productDao;
    }

//    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
//        this.products = products;
//    }
}
```

I'have already done a lot of research in google and so on, but I can't just get a good answer to my problem, and I've seen a lot more people with the same problem or almost the same.

I already have the necessary jars in the classpath and in the WEB-INF/lib folder (I mean, I do think so)

- antlr-2.7.6
- aspectjweaver
- commons-collections-3.1
- commons-dbcp-1.4
- commons-logging
- commons-pool
- dom4j-1.6.1
- ehcache-1.1
- hibernate3
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
- hsqldb
- javassist-3.12.0.GA
- jstl
- jta-1.1
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin
- slf4j-api-1.6.1
- slf4j-simple-1.6.1
- spring
- spring-test
- spring-webmvc
- standard
- standard-1.0.2

I'm doing the project with Eclipse.

**Edited**

This happens when I start or restart the server.

**Edited**

**Solved! Seems it was library conflicts**

Comment: Can you double check that commons-dbcp-1.4 is in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: it's there, no doubt about that

Comment: @Bierbatovsky would you mind telling us in detail which jar conflicted? becuase I have the same problem and wanna figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add jar file in your build path..

commons-dbcp-1.1-RC2.jar

or any version of that..!!!!

**ADDED** : also make sure you have **commons-pool-1.1.jar** too in your build path.

**ADDED**: sorry saw complete list of jar late... may be version clashes might be there.. better check out..!!! just an assumption.

Comment: can you just send over the complete source code??
i mean if you dont have any constraints..
coz it'll simplify a lot to debug..!!!!

Comment: there's no prob, but it could be a litle difficult to send it by here. It has 13,5 MB

Comment: mail it if possible on indyaah@gmail.com
and as m leaving for the day from office..
u ll need to wait till tomorrow.. :(

Comment: ok, already sent you the project with the subject "Widesys - Help on Web Java Project" anything you don't understand in code mail me. ty!

Comment: I already solved it! Seems it was some library conflicts. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stack trace, your issue is that your app cannot find `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`, as per this line:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
```

I see that you have commons-dbcp in your list of jars, but for whatever reason, your app is not finding the `BasicDataSource` class in it.

Comment: yeah, I had already noticed that and I've tried remove the build path, adding it, other versions of the jars, restarting eclipse, the machine, cleaning server, etc..

Comment: nothing seems to work :/ can it be some eclipse bug or something?

Comment: It could be, but it is more likely that something is set up incorrectly on your machine.

Comment: I thought about that, but what could it be??

Comment: If you right click on your project and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path, you should see what Eclipse thinks you have on your classpath.  Take a look at the libraries tab, if you do not see your commons-dbcp, then it is not finding it.  If that is the case, click the Add JARs... button, and navigate to the path that contains the JARs you need.  Add it, and clean/build your project and try again.

Comment: I already solved it! Seems it was some library conflicts. But thanks anyway.