# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: spring, maven, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, tomcat8

I am facing this Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved.
It looks like that there is a library conflict in Maven dependencies.

Some of dependencies are:

```
org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.1.02
org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.12
org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.2.7
```

I changed version of eclipse link and JSF version after that I added dependency for this missing class (org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved) from [here](https://1maven.com/classname-packaging?query&cl=PersistenceWeaved&pk=org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving&pg=5&a=&s=#t_).

Nothing fits to my issue yet.

I have read about this issue below

[org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026924/org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-error-creating-bean-wit)
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2545395?db=5

I've already done a lot of research in google and so on, but I can't just get a good answer to my problem, and I've seen a lot more people with the same problem or [almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026924/org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-error-creating-bean-wit).

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/bootstrap-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
>     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
>     at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/weaving/PersistenceWeaved
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2503)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.specificToGenericStringHeader(Method.java:419)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Executable.sharedToGenericString(Executable.java:163)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.toGenericString(Method.java:414)
>     at java.beans.MethodRef.set(MethodRef.java:46)
>     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:117)
>     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
>     at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1205)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
>     at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
>     at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:224)
>     at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:149)
>     at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:324)
>     at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:331)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1242)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     ... 56 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeaved
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>     ... 90 more

Comment: The web app is configured and runs on Tomcat 7.0.57. However, I need to migrate it to newer version of Tomcat e.g. 8.0.33. It looks that there was an issue regarding eclipselink and Tomcat 8.0.33.
Can you advise me where could be a problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

Please, add this org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.1.02 jar file to lib folder inside of apache tomcat folder.
This solve this issue on Apache Tomcat 8.0.33.